# PDO setAttribute with PDOException

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo

This my function that currently using:

```
function pdo_connect(){
  try {

      $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);     
      $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );           
      $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  } catch (PDOException $e) {

      die("Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>");

  }

  return $pdo;
}
```

But consider that I used this

```
$pdo->setAttribute( INVALID_SYNTAX, false );
```

**I don't want to see fatal error:**

> Fatal error:  Undefined class constant 'INVALID_SYNTAX' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 12

I want to catch in exception, then How to do that/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An undefined constant error is not an exception, but a *compilation error*. It's like a syntax error, it's something that's a fundamental error in your code that needs to be fixed. It doesn't make sense to catch it at runtime. It's also not actually possible.

The constant `INVALID_SYNTAX` would also never trigger an "undefined *class* constant" error, only a "plain" *undefined constant* error.

---

Exceptions are there to handle *exceptional* errors during runtime. Exceptional errors are errors that *should not happen* during normal execution, but you are prepared in case they do.
A mistyped constant is *always* going to cause an error, and always the same error. It's not *exceptional*, it's simply wrong code. It therefore makes no sense to want to handle it at runtime dynamically.

Comment: oh so there is no way to catch it?

Comment: You cannot *catch* it since it's not a *thrown* exception. You could *error handle* it using a custom error handler, but it's a non-recoverable error, so there's nothing much for you to do even if you did.

Comment: To clarify the answer: this has actually nothing to do with PDO. This is how PHP handles undefined constants (either regular constants or class constants). You can write custom error handlers but, if I recall correctly, fatal errors are not catchable.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is **no point** in catching *development phase errors*.

A constant can be undefined only in the development phase. And there is no use in catching it - a developer just have to define it and move on.

Exceptions is one of the most misunderstood mechanisms in PHP. Although they actually have to be used ONLY in case when **a recoverable error can be handled** somehow, PHP users exploit it in all but proper ways: for the error reporting, data validation or as an error suppression operator.

Comment: Then it does not matter if its setAttribute or any other command.

Comment: Yes. that's what deceze said exactly - indeed it doesn't matter